# AMSbook documentclass and exsheets problem

Tags: amsbook, exsheets

I think that there is a problem when you use task lists in amsbook class. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[load-headings, load-tasks]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin-fixed-nr,counter-format=ch.qu}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Let $f(x)$ etc etc  
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
ddd
\end{solution}
\begin{question}
\begin{tasks}
\task First choice 
\task Second choice
\task Third choice
\end{tasks}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: Interesting... I'll investigate. Meanwhile you can always use `enumerate` (the `enumitem` package makes it easy to get it with enumerated with a), b), c)...).

Comment: The `tasks` package doesn't take cases into account when `\listparindent` is non-zero... :( I'll send a fixed version to https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/wiki/Home later today and send an update to CTAN soon after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem of the `exsheets` *package* but an issue with the `tasks` package that is loaded by `exsheets` and is distributed as part of the `exsheets` bundle. It didn't take a non-zero `\listparindent` into account.

This is fixed in `tasks` v0.9b 2013/12/03 (arrived in TeX Live today):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\usepackage{tasks}[2013/12/02]
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  \task Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  \task Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\par
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}
  \task Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  \task Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.\par
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]